# Desktop/server search engine with night time indexing

Tags: search, search-engines, desktop-search, google-desktop-search

Is there some desktop/server search engine (such as Google Desktop or Copernic) satisfying the below requests.

---

*Requests:*

1. Must work on Windows server and Windows 7 environments.
2. Indexing can be scheduled.
3. Fast search using index file.
4. Search targets should be content and titles of MS Outlook mails, *.txt, *.doc, *.xls etc.

---

*Nice to have:*

1. Possibility to set search targets e.g. uncompiled computer code (which are usually text files but with less usual extensions such as *.p, *.i, *.cls etc.)
2. Freeware.

---

Comment: I could of sworn the OS comes with an indexer that throttles itself.